# Assigning results of strsplit to multiple columns of data frame

Tags: r, multiple-columns, strsplit

I am trying to split a character vector into three different vectors, inside a data frame.

My data is something like:

```
> df <- data.frame(filename = c("Author1 (2010) Title of paper", 
                                "Author2 et al (2009) Title of paper",
                                "Author3 & Author4 (2004) Title of paper"),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And I would like to split those 3 informations (`authors`, `year`, `title`) into three different columns, so that it would be:

```
> df
                          filename             author  year   title
 1           Author1 (2010) Title1            Author1  2010  Title1
 2     Author2 et al (2009) Title2      Author2 et al  2009  Title2
 3 Author3 & Author4 (2004) Title3  Author3 & Author4  2004  Title3
```

I have used `strsplit` to split each `filename` in a vector of 3 elements:

```
 df$temp <- strsplit(df$filename, " \\(|\\) ")
```

But now, I can't find a way to put each element in a separate column. I can access a specific information like that:

```
> df$temp[[2]][1]
[1] "Author2 et al"
```

but can't find how to put it in the other columns

```
> df$author <- df$temp[[]][1]
Error
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the `tidyr` package, here's a `separate` solution:

```
separate(df, "filename", c("Author","Year","Title"), sep=" \\(|\\) "), remove=F)
#                                  filename            Author
# 1           Author1 (2010) Title of paper           Author1
# 2     Author2 et al (2009) Title of paper     Author2 et al
# 3 Author3 & Author4 (2004) Title of paper Author3 & Author4
#   Year          Title
# 1 2010 Title of paper
# 2 2009 Title of paper
# 3 2004 Title of paper
```

Leading and trailing spaces have been accounted for

Answer (score 7):

You could try `tstrsplit` from the devel version of `data.table`

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 setDT(df)[, c('author', 'year', 'title') :=tstrsplit(filename, ' \\(|\\) ')]
df
#                                  filename             author year
#1:           Author1 (2010) Title of paper           Author1  2010
#2:     Author2 et al (2009) Title of paper     Author2 et al  2009
#3: Author3 & Author4 (2004) Title of paper Author3 & Author4  2004
#             title
#1:  Title of paper
#2:  Title of paper
#3:  Title of paper
```

Edit: Included OP's split pattern to remove the white spaces.

Answer (score 6):

```
result <- cbind(df, do.call("rbind", strsplit(df$filename, " \\(|\\) ")))
colnames(result)[2:4] <- c("author", "year", "title")
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a base `t`-method (transpose) for dataframes:

```
 res <- t( data.frame(  strsplit(df$filename, " \\(|\\) ") ))
 colnames(res) <- c("author", "year", "title")
 rownames(res) <- seq_along(rownames(res) )
 res
#--------------
  author              year   title           
1 "Author1"           "2010" "Title of paper"
2 "Author2 et al"     "2009" "Title of paper"
3 "Author3 & Author4" "2004" "Title of paper"
```

Comment: Great! At the end, I did this: 
    `df <- cbind(df, t( data.frame(  strsplit(df$filename, " \\(|\\) ") ) ) );
    colnames(df)[colnames(df) == "1"] <- "author";
    colnames(df)[colnames(df) == "2"] <- "year";
    colnames(df)[colnames(df) == "3"] <- "title";
    rownames(df) <- NULL`