# R: Split Variable Column into multiple (unbalanced) columns by comma

Tags: r, split

I have a dataset of 25 variables and over 2 million observations. One of my variables is a combination of a few different "categories" that I want to split to where it shows 1 category per column (similar to what split would do in stata). For example:

```
# Name      Age     Number               Events                      First 
# Karen      24        8         Triathlon/IM,Marathon,10k,5k         0
# Kurt       39        2         Half-Marathon,10k                    0 
# Leah       18        0                                              1
```

And I want it to look like:

```
# Name   Age  Number Events_1        Event_2      Events_3     Events_4      First
# Karen   24    8     Triathlon/IM    Marathon       10k         5k             0
# Kurt    39    2     Half-Marathon   10k            NA          NA             0 
# Leah    18    0     NA              NA             NA          NA             1
```

I have looked through stackoverflow but have not found anything that works (everything gives me an error of some sort). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Note: May not be important but the largest number of categories 1 person has is 19 therefore I would need to create Event_1:Event_19

Comment: Previous stack overflows have suggested the separate function, however this function does not seem to work with my dataset. When I input the function the program runs but when it is finished nothing is changed, there is no output, and no error code. When I tried to use other suggestions made in other threads I received error messages. However, I finally got it is work by using the cSplit function. Thank for the help!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning results of strsplit to multiple columns of data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357963/assigning-results-of-strsplit-to-multiple-columns-of-data-frame)

Comment: another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18641951/2372064

Comment: If you use `separate` from `tidyr` (answer in the duplicate question), just add `extra='drop'` to pad out the non-existing ones with NA.

Comment: `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package should do what you're asking for.

Comment: For some reason the separate package does not work, an error does not show up but when the program stops running the dataset is unchanged and there is no output.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, cSplit is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From Ananda's `splitstackshape` package:

```
cSplit(df, "Events", sep=",")
#    Name Age Number First      Events_1 Events_2 Events_3 Events_4
#1: Karen  24      8     0  Triathlon/IM Marathon      10k       5k
#2:  Kurt  39      2     0 Half-Marathon      10k       NA       NA
#3: Leah   18      0     1            NA       NA       NA       NA
```

Or with `tidyr`:

```
separate(df, 'Events', paste("Events", 1:4, sep="_"), sep=",", extra="drop")
#   Name Age Number               Events_1 Events_2 Events_3 Events_4 First
#1 Karen  24      8           Triathlon/IM Marathon      10k       5k     0
#2  Kurt  39      2          Half-Marathon      10k     <NA>     <NA>     0
#3 Leah   18      0                     NA     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     1
```

With the `data.table` package:

```
setDT(df)[,paste0("Events_", 1:4) := tstrsplit(Events, ",")][,-"Events", with=F]
#    Name Age Number First               Events_1 Events_2 Events_3 Events_4
#1: Karen  24      8     0           Triathlon/IM Marathon      10k       5k
#2:  Kurt  39      2     0          Half-Marathon      10k       NA       NA
#3: Leah   18      0     1                     NA       NA       NA       NA
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Karen", "Kurt", 
"Leah "), class = "factor"), Age = c(24L, 39L, 18L), Number = c(8L, 
2L, 0L), Events = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("               NA", 
"         Half-Marathon,10k", "     Triathlon/IM,Marathon,10k,5k"
), class = "factor"), First = c(0L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("Name", 
"Age", "Number", "Events", "First"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Or `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, paste0('Events', 1:4):= tstrsplit(Events, ',')]`