# R tidyr: use separate function to separate character column with comma-separated text into multiple columns using RegEx

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, tidyr, regex-lookarounds

I have the following dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("one", "one, two", "two, three", "one, two, three"))
```

It looks like this

```
                x
1             one
2        one, two
3      two, three
4 one, two, three
```

I would like to be able to separate this `x` column into many different columns, one for every **distinct** word in the column `x`. Basically I would like the final result to be something like this

```
    one  two  three
1    1    0     0
2    1    1     0
3    0    1     1
4    1    1     1
```

I think that in order to obtain that dataframe, I probably need to be able to use the `separate` function provided by `tidyr` and documented [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html). However, this requires knowledge of regular expressions, and I'm not good with them. Can anyone help me obtain this dataframe?

IMPORTANT: I do not know the number, nor the spelling of the words a priori.

## Important Example

It should work also with empty strings. For instance if we have

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("one", "one, two", "two, three", "one, two, three", ""))
```

then it should also work.

Comment: Try `library(splitstackshape); cSplit_e(df, split.col = "x", fixed = TRUE, type = "character", drop = TRUE, fill = 0L)`

Comment: Possible dupe: [R: Split Variable Column into multiple (unbalanced) columns by comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577423/r-split-variable-column-into-multiple-unbalanced-columns-by-comma)

Comment: @markus I'll look at that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tidyverse`, we can use `separate_rows` to split up the 'x' column, create a sequence column and use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   filter(!(is.na(x)|x==""))%>% 
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   separate_rows(x) %>%
   mutate(i1 = 1) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = x, values_from = i1, , values_fill = list(i1 = 0)) %>%
   select(-rn)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#    one   two three
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     0     0
#2     1     1     0
#3     0     1     1
#4     1     1     1
```

In the above code, the `rn` column was added to have distinct identifier for each rows after we expand the rows with `separate_rows`, otherwise, it can result in a `list` output column in `pivot_wider` when there are duplicate elements.  The 'i1' with value 1 is added to be used in the `values_from`.  Another option is to specify `values_fn = length`

---

Or we can use `table` after splitting the 'x' column in `base R`

```
table(stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(df$x), ",\\s+"), seq_len(nrow(df))))[2:1])
```

Comment: I love the `tidyverse` solution. Would you be able to add some more explanation to it? I can see it works, but not 100% sure why. The first `mutate` creates a column with row numbers. Then `separate_rows` somehow separates the comma-delimited words into a single row for each word. Then you create a column of `1`s with `mutate`... and this is where I get lost

Comment: When I try this with a different dataset (containing NA values) the tidyverse solution throws an error.

Comment: @Euler_Salter can you please update your post with an example.  I couldn't get an error with `df <- data.frame(x=c("one", "one, two", "two, three", "one, two, three", NA))`

Comment: Will do in a second!

Comment: It actually fails with `""` rather than NA. I'll post an example

Comment: when `df <- data.frame(x=c("one", "one, two", "two, three", "one, two, three", ""))` I get `Error: Column 4 must be named.
Use .name_repair to specify repair.`

Comment: @Euler_Salter You can either convert the `""` to `NA` or use `filter` i.e. `df %>% filter(x != "") %>%  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
+    separate_rows(x) %>%
+    mutate(i1 = 1) %>% 
+    pivot_wider(names_from = x, values_from = i1, , values_fill = list(i1 = 0)) %>%
+    select(-rn)`

Comment: I am, there’s something failing in my real use case. I’ll get back to you as soon possible

Comment: Okay, I think I know where the problem is. In my example I have rows such as `"one and two, one, two"` and `"two and three, one, three"`. So I think the only tweek needed is to use `separate_rows(x, sep=",")`

Comment: @Euler_Salter. In that case, you can add the `sep = "\\s*[and,]\\s*")`

Comment: What does it do? I basically it needs to be able to work on normal strings such as `one, two` (here it would get `one` and `two`), on strings ending in a comma `one, two,` (here would get `one` and `two`) and in empty strings `""`

Comment: to me `one and two` is to be considered different from both `one` and from `two`

Comment: @Euler_Salter ok, in that caes, just use the previous `sep="\\s*,\\s*"`

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out! I've asked you a lot of things, but you managed to handle all of them, well done!!

Comment: Would you be able to help me with a very similar problem, the main difference is how the information is extracted from the character column?

Comment: @Euler_Salter Sure, is it a new question

Comment: Yes, I'm about to finish writing it

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515177/r-tidyr-regex-extract-ordered-numbers-from-character-column

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution

```
# split strings by ", " and save in to a list `lst`
lst <- apply(df, 1, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x,", ")))

# a common set including all distinct words
common <- Reduce(union,lst)

# generate matrix which is obtained by checking if `common` can be found in the array in `lst`
dfout <- `names<-`(data.frame(Reduce(rbind,lapply(lst, function(x) +(common %in% x))),row.names = NULL),common)
```

such that

```
> dfout
  one two three
1   1   0     0
2   1   1     0
3   0   1     1
4   1   1     1
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be working. Can you comment it a bit?

Comment: @Euler_Salter Yes, I added some comments, please see my updates

Comment: Can you explain `names<-`?

Also I am having a hard time understanding `Reduce` from `?Reduce`. Thanks!

Comment: @its.me.adam `names<-(x,val)` assign names to the object, which is equivalent to `names(x) <- vals`. for `Reduce`, maybe you can get more information from https://blog.zhaw.ch/datascience/r-reduce-applys-lesser-known-brother/

Answer (score 1):

You could build a pattern from your columns and use it with `tidyr::extract()` :

```r
library(tidyverse)
cols <- c("one","two","three")
pattern <- paste0("(",cols,")*", collapse= "(?:, )*")
df %>% 
  extract(x, into = c("one","two","three"), regex = pattern) %>%
  mutate_all(~as.numeric(!is.na(.)))
#>   one two three
#> 1   1   0     0
#> 2   1   1     0
#> 3   0   1     1
#> 4   1   1     1
```