# R tidyr regex: extract ordered numbers from character column

Tags: r, regex, tidyr, regex-lookarounds

Suppose I have a data frame like this

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("This script outputs 10 visualizations.", 
                     "This script outputs 1 visualization.", 
                     "This script outputs 5 data files.", 
                     "This script outputs 1 data file.", 
                     "This script doesn't output any visualizations or data files", 
                     "This script outputs 9 visualizations and 28 data files.", 
                     "This script outputs 1 visualization and 1 data file."))
```

It looks like this

```
                                                            x
1                      This script outputs 10 visualizations.
2                        This script outputs 1 visualization.
3                           This script outputs 5 data files.
4                            This script outputs 1 data file.
5 This script doesn't output any visualizations or data files
6     This script outputs 9 visualizations and 28 data files.
7        This script outputs 1 visualization and 1 data file.
```

Is there a simple way, possibly using the `Tidyverse` to extract the number of visualizations and the number of files for each row? When there are no visualizations (or no data files, or both) I would like to extract `0`. Essentially I would like the final result to be like this

```
    viz   files
1    10       0
2     1       0
3     0       5
4     0       1
5     0       0
6     9      28
7     1       1
```

I tried using stuff like

```
str_extract(df$x, "(?<=This script outputs )(.*)(?= visualizatio(n\\.$|ns\\.$))")
```

but I got so lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use regex lookaround in `str_extract` to extract one or more digits (`\\d+`) followed by a space and 'vis' or 'data files' into two columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  transmute(viz = as.numeric(str_extract(x, "\\d+(?= vis)")),
            files = as.numeric(str_extract(x, "\\d+(?= data files?)"))) %>%
  mutate_all(replace_na, 0)
#  viz files
#1  10     0
#2   1     0
#3   0     5
#4   0     0
#5   0     0
#6   9    28
#7   1     0
```

In the first case, the pattern matches one or more digits (`\\d+`) followed by a regex lookaround (`(?=`) where there is a space followed by the 'vis' word and in second column, it extracts the digits followed by the space and the word 'file' or 'files'

Comment: Could you please modify it so that it works on both `data file` and `data files`?

Comment: Oh I recon I just replace `data files` with `data fil`

Comment: I know very little about regex, do you mind writing a small paragraph explaining what the symbols are doing?

Comment: @Euler_Salter. I added the `s?` to make sure that it would also process even if there is no `s` at the end.  Suree, will update

Answer (score 4):

You could use the package *unglue* to get a readable solution as you have a limited amount of possible patterns, then replace NAs by 0 :

```r
library(unglue)
patterns <-
  c("This script outputs {viz} visualization{=s{0,1}} and {files} data file{=s{0,1}}.",
    "This script outputs {viz} visualization{=s{0,1}}.",
    "This script outputs {files} data file{=s{0,1}}.")

res <- unglue_unnest(df, x, patterns, convert = TRUE) 
res[is.na(res)] <- 0
res
#>   viz files
#> 1  10     0
#> 2   1     0
#> 3   0     5
#> 4   0     1
#> 5   0     0
#> 6   9    28
#> 7   1     1
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R approach ...

```
df$viz <- as.numeric(sub(".*This script outputs (\\d+).*", "\\1", df$x))
df$files <- as.numeric(sub(".*(\\d+) data file.*", "\\1", df$x))
df[is.na(df)] <- 0

df
#                                                             x viz files
# 1                      This script outputs 10 visualizations.  10     0
# 2                        This script outputs 1 visualization.   1     0
# 3                           This script outputs 5 data files.   5     5
# 4                            This script outputs 1 data file.   1     1
# 5 This script doesn't output any visualizations or data files   0     0
# 6     This script outputs 9 visualizations and 28 data files.   9    28
# 7        This script outputs 1 visualization and 1 data file.   1     1
```

Comment: Very close! I'd like the NA to be zeros, but apart from that, that looks good